# Bootstrap 3 Affix dynamic values.

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I can not get the dynamic values to change after the page has loaded so if the page height is changed then so is the affix height.

I have had a look at some other code but I cant figure it out, this is what I have so far:

```
$('#navigation').affix({
    offset: {
        top: $('#hero').height()
    }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/livagepe/1/